# Import/Export file into Flutter application

Tags: file, flutter, import, export

I'd like to implement an import/export functionality in my flutter application. The user should be able to save data as json and export it via e.g. mail and another user should then be able to import this json file into his application. I couldn't find anything helpful yet. Is it even possible yet?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Look this package: https://pub.dev/packages/share, maybe help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**use** [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) package to import file

to export json data via e.g email convert data to byte

and then

**use** [share](https://pub.dev/packages/share) package  to share it with email or facebook etc..

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create, save, and read files on your device using path_provider library.

https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

Another library is file_picker to pick different files from your device and use it as you wish.

https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

For sharing files you may use share library

https://pub.dev/packages/share

Be sure to go through the documentation for implementation and best practices.